# Firefox will not start (no window)

Tags: windows, firefox, windows-10

I have the latest Firefox version, and am running Windows 10 Home 64-bit, preinstalled on a new laptop (Acer). Firefox starts (the process appears in Task Manager) but no window appears. Trying to start it always works ONE time; then it never starts again, until I clear the profiles folder completely. Then the same thing happens.

P.S.
I configured Windows 10 manually and with help from spybot anti beacon. Everything that can be disabled is disabled.

Comment: Have you started in safe mode: `{PathTo}Firefox.exe -safe-mode`? Are there any plug-ins (as opposed to add-ons)?

Comment: Do you have a second monitor which isn't switched on (or connected), where the Firefox window could be appearing?

Comment: @AFH: I've already started in safe mode, but that doesn't change anything. Concerning plugins: I've tried with and without (blank install and install with following import of the profiles folder.

Comment: @Andrew Morton: No. I didn't try a second monitor so far. Firefox always starts normally once (when I cleared the profiles folder before and canceled each process concerning firefox in the task manager.

Comment: One other thought: when the window disappears, is there still a task-bar entry? If so, position the mouse over it, hold `Shift` and right-click, and then select `Maximise`. If the window appears, then when restored normally it is off-screen, and you should be able to bring it back with `Shift` and right-click, and select `Move` or `Size`.

Comment: `firefox last version` Please state the specific build you are currently using as the latest version will change over time.

Answer (score 0):

comodo firewall was my issue, must be a kernel hook?
#
I stripped all the old libraries "runtimes C++ NET" and randomly installed applications on the system. "the junk you forget!"
#
until I had just "office", ccleaner, and only video drivers "freshly updated" 
and boom... 
#
firefox 64bit worked.. i was getting ready for a clean reinstall and pulling all my stuff off the drive, to a USB rescue device.
#
windows 7 64bit and firefox 62.0.2 :)

Answer (score -1):

Also, try to run the application under all users. (Built-in admin, admin, standard user,guest) Then, it would be a good idea to reinstall Firefox and clear the registry with regedit. If the above fails, I think that you could try to run derivatives of Firefox, like waterfox...in order to understand from where does the problems roots.

Comment: I've already started firefox as admin. Also I deinstalled firefox with my usual routine (checking all appropriate folders in windows explorer after deinstallation, cleaning the registry manually and with ccleaner afterwards, cleaning the system with extended disk cleanup and new system start afterwards). No effect. I just found out that my 32bit Installation of firefox works quiet reliable, but the 64bit one doesn't. mostly the 64bit one only starts normally when I started and closed the 32bit one before.